# How to stream AWS DynamoDB data to Gephi or other graph visualization tool?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graph-visualization, gephi

I have installed Gephi's graph streaming plugin that allows you to stream data from a database into Gephi, showing a network of your data. I have my data in a AWS DynamoDB table, but don't know how to connect that table's data to Gephi so that I can visualize it.

A source URL is required in Gephi, so I need to figure out what the DynamoDB table's source URL is, or find an alternative method of visualizing my DynamoDB data.

I am new to all of this so any help is appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Gephi yet, but had a project where I sourced data from [dynamoDB local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) onto  [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org) . I believe you may need to change extracted data little bit to map to your requirements.

Difference between dynamoDB local and remote is just swapping our source URL and credentials. Rest of the code ports as is.

**DynamoDB Local:**
Install [dynamoDB local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) which is basically download and extract of jar file and initiate DB as below:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar --cors "*"
```

**DynamoDB Tables:**
I had two table, one for edges and one for nodes. You can have one for both nodes & edges as well.

**Data in dynamoDB local:**

You can upload data to DynamoDB in following format. Examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.01.html) are similar to what's needed to create / upload and fetch graph data.

Basically have a db with something similar as below.

For nodes table:
"id" as hash key.
"nodeName" as range key.

For edges table:
"id" as hash key.
"edgeName" as range key.

**Sourcing from dynamoDB local:**

Once DB is created, and data uploaded, you can source from local db using js promise. Wrap Cytoscape under the promise. You will need to do some ETL on data from dynamoDB to map to Cytoscape (here) or Gephi in your case.

**Relevant Code**:

```
AWS.config.update({
          region: "us-east-1",
          endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
          accessKeyId: "MyFakeKeyId",
          secretAccessKey: "MyFakeSecretAccessKey"
        });
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    //nodeDB params
    var params1 = {
            TableName: "yourNodeDB",
    }
    //edgeDB params
    var params2 = {
            TableName: "yourEdgeDB",
    }

var promise1 = docClient.scan(params1).promise();
var promise2 = docClient.scan(params2).promise();

// Get table data after promise is fulfilled.
Promise.all([ promise1,promise2])
.then (function(data) { 

    // process node data
    var graphData = [];
    data[0].Items.forEach(function(n) { 
        graphData.push({ data: n })
    });

    // process edge data
    data[1].Items.forEach(function(e) { 
        graphData.push({ data: e })
    });

    //Init Cytoscape Graph
    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({ 
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        ..
        ..
        elements: graphData,
    });
});
```